# Expressionengine multilangual htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, redirection

Having a hard time getting a multilingual site to work ( not complete getting the htaccess syntax)
folder layout 
root 
 - /en
 - /ar

My htaccess is interfering with some of the system act links as far as i can see giving me 500 errors here and there . below I attached my current htaccess ( AR is a modification of the en so not included ) and index.php edits for the root , /en(/ar) folders.

I want the site to default to en/ jump to the en folder. But something is wrong in my htaccess(s) I think, as the system act-links sometimes return 500 errors, please have a look any suggestions is appreciated, Thanks.

The root htaccess and index.php :

[image]
[image]

The /en(ar) htaccess and index.php :

[image]
[image]

Comment: After looking at it - perhaps the site should not redirect the root to /en. But perhaps just use the site_url set with the /en prefix so on first click it goes there.

Comment: Would still appreciate some directions on the htaccess files. 
i know in IIS you can clear/override previous rules - Don't know if this just happens automaticly with Htaccess